# How to use custom type in user-defined function?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, udf

I need to write a user defined function with a specific types as inputs

```
spark.udf.register("udf", (p:Point) => distance(p.x, p.y))
```

I created a case class Point

```
case class Point(val x: Double, val y: Double)
```

When I use the udf in an Sql query, it is not working. Any help?

Comment: In SQL query, does "Point" type is available? calling UDF you need to pass column which has data type as "Point"

Comment: No Point type does not exist, how to define it?

Answer (score 2):

Define your case class and use it as the "source" of the schema for your datasets.

```
case class Point(val x: Double, val y: Double)
val points = Seq(Point(0,0), Point(0,1)).toDF
scala> points.show
+---+---+
|  x|  y|
+---+---+
|0.0|0.0|
|0.0|1.0|
+---+---+
```

As you may have noticed, the case class becomes a mere schema (i.e. structure) of your dataset. In other words, you cannot write a user-defined function that would accept `Point` objects while processing such datasets.

A possible solution is not to use a user-defined function, but typed `Dataset` and register the function not as a UDF but a regular Scala function (or method).

```
scala> val points = Seq(Point(0,0), Point(0,1)).toDS
points: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[Point] = [x: double, y: double]

def distance(x: Double, y: Double) = y - x
val myFn = (p:Point) => distance(p.x, p.y)
scala> points.map(myFn).show
+-----+
|value|
+-----+
|  0.0|
|  1.0|
+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your exact requirement, but looking at your code, I am suggesting some logic.

Hope your query/table have two separate values as X and Y.
You can reframe your udf as below

```
spark.udf.register("udf", (x:Double, y:Double) => distance(x,y))
```

Now you can use new udf using `withCoumn()` and pass two separate parameters X and Y

Let me know know anything else is expected.

Comment: @syl please make the answer as correct if it works for you

Comment: This still not gonna solve the case that if you have nested Custom types